# how to lift a column by one row up in a data with group structures

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have the following mock data file *df*.

I want to lift *response* by one row up within each *group*.

So that every '1' value of *X* within each *group* would correspond to '2' of *response*, '2' of *X* would correspond to '3' of *response*, and so on. Every 10th value in *X* has to get deleted.

[image]

Any suggesetions guys?

UPDATE:

So the output has to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Please make a reproducible example so the question could be answered. one simple way is `df$response = c(df$response[-1], NA)` then `df <- df[df$X != 10,]`

Comment: @RicVillalba , by 'reproducible example' do you mean how the output has to look like?

Comment: but anyway, your suggestion hit it right, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  mutate(X = lag(X))
```

if you have the latest version of `dplyr` do:

```
df %>%
  mutate(X = lag(X), .by=group)
```